# AWS Lambda over a second delay when pulling data from Dynamo Db

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have been going through some tutorials on AWS Lambda & Dynamodb. I see that, just to get a response with one record which is all the Dyanamodb table has as of now, I see there is a delay of little over a second. My intention is to use aws services for a chat application in the future, but this delay wont be acceptable for a chat application.

How the function is called -
I invoke the lambda function using the API Gateway, and the Lambda function in turn calls the Dynamodb table, returns the response through the function and finally through the API back to the user.

Lambda Code -

```
 const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
 const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({region:'ca-central-1', apiVersion:'2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = (event,context,callback) => {
    const params = {
        Item: {
            "UserId": {
                S:"user_" + Math.random()
            },
            "Age": {
                N:event.age
            },
            "Height": {
                N:event.height
            },
            "Income": {
                N:event.income
            }
        },
        TableName: "compare-yourself"
    };
    dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: How do you measure the delay? You invoke the lambda using the AWS consoles "Test" button for lambda?

Comment: I am not literally measuring it, but I know for sure it takes over a sec to see my response message in the browser console.  I do the Test on API Gateway and also I have created a API invoke function using codepen in nodejs. Added but more details on the invocation to the original post.

Comment: what size is your lambda function's memory in MB?

Comment: Can you show the code please ?

Comment: @LRutten its 128mb

Comment: @Yasen I have added the code to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to increase your lambda RAM to approximately 1GB and try again. Often high latencies are caused by small lambda sizes.

Increasing memory also improves other performance  metrics likes CPU and therefore generally reduces latency caused by lambda cold starts. Especially lambdas smaller than 512MB are relatively slow to start.

Comment: Currently I am on the free tier that AWS provides. If I can bring down the delay by increasing the memory thats all I need to know. Thanks LRutten.

Comment: I'd suggest you just try it out. Even 1000 invocations with 1GB would be about 0.005 dollar (less than a cent).

Comment: Okay sure will test it out.